# Is it safe to subclass basic framework classes?

Tags: java, android

I realize that future API versions will (mostly) be backwards compatible regarding methods, but can I "safely" create my own `MyTextView.class` that extends `TextView`, or will this likely break with the next major API version update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with extending those classes. If you are really concerned about backwards compatibility you can extend [App Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html)

> These Support Library classes provide backward-compatible
>   implementations of important, core platform features. These
>   implementation typically extend earlier versions of the class to
>   handle new methods and features added in more recent releases of the
>   platform. Some of these classes are complete, static implementations
>   of the framework APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, unless the relevant Javadoc says otherwise, subclassing a class is no more likely to cause breaking changes with an upgrade than using it in any other standard way.